# Display error messsage on pop-up label in ASP.NET MVC Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on login in functionality. The login form displays in Modal(bootstrap). When user provide correct credentials it is redirecting correctly. If user provides incorrect details, I needs to display the error message on that pop-up itself. I used RedirectToAction to same page. But How can I make my pop-up to be stand-by if credentials were wrong. currently the pop-up is closing.
My code is as follows :

```
 <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

                @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "regForm" }))
                {

                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">
                        <fieldset>
                            <!-- Sign Up Form -->
                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control input-large", @placeholder = "Joek@irawath.com", @required = "" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { @class = "form-control input-large", @placeholder = "Joek@irawath.com", @required = "" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Password input-->
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-large", @placeholder = "********", @required = "", @type = "password" })

                                    <em>1-8 Characters</em>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="reenterpassword">Re-Enter Password:</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input id="reenterpassword" class="form-control" name="reenterpassword" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <!-- Button -->
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <button id="btnconfirmsignup" type="submit" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                                    @* <button id="btnsignin" type="submit" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Sign In</button>*@

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                }



            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <center>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </center>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller Code :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckUser(UserInfo obj)
    {

        int res = udaObj.CheckUser(obj.UserName, obj.Password);
        if (res >= 1)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Appointment", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            //For testing purpose
            return RedirectToAction("NewIndex", "Home");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use Ajax for this. It's very easy.

Comment: I don't want to use ajax. Because user can't understand what's happening ? The processing symbol of browser will be calm if I use ajax.

Comment: If you use `RedirectToAction`, even to the same URL of the current page, it's akin to clicking on a link that takes you back to that page, hence why the modal disappears (the page reloaded). As @BasantaMatia mentioned, AJAX is probably better suited to this situation, and if you're concerned about users not knowing what's happening, then add a spinner or loading bar to indicate work in progress. That's not really a strong argument to avoid using AJAX.

Comment: @sleeyuen , The modal disappears, because it's getting postback by doing RedirectToAction.

Comment: How can I use here pprogress bar on my pop-up. I'm very beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do it using `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

[**I have written a blog here**](http://www.nestedclasses.com/Blog/MVC/1) on `Asynchronous Login/Sign up` in `ASP.Net MVC` and `Bootstrap Modal popup`. Step by step everything is there, even you can download the project it self.

All these features you can achieve from that blog,

1) Login/Signup in a Bootstrap Modal

2) If credentials are valid, it's redirecting to another page

3) If credentials are wrong it will show proper error message in Modal itself

4) Loading image and button after submit click

Cheers :)